# Is it safe to create new thread in a loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it safe to create new thread inside while loop? I have tried this way:

```
std::thread thread(ClientLoop,clientSocket)
```

But as soon as the function return it throws the error.

```
while (true){
    cout << "Waiting for new connections" << endl;
    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
    cout << "Client connected" << endl;
    new thread(ClientLoop,clientSocket);                
}
```

This way it works, but I wonder if there are no memory leaks. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Could it be a stack overflow as this is an infinite loop simply accepting too many connections?

Comment: it throws R6010 - abort() has been called

Comment: Note that spawning a new thread is *expensive*. It's quite possible that processing the data serially will take more time than creating the thread, so don't do this blindly hoping for easy parallelism.

Comment: You should check `listenSocket` to see if it's valid. Then check `clientSocket` and if it's invalid, `break;`. Not to mention the dangling `new thread` pointer. If `accept` fails it'll keep failing in an infinite loop, guess what'll happen to your memory... **You are definitely coming to C++ from a managed language and you're doing it wrong.** Not to mention that the 1 thread per client model is exhausted pretty quickly. For many clients (4+ digits), use IOCP or `boost::asio` for cross-platform.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> as soon as the function return it throws the error

Indeed, you mustn't destroy a joinable thread object. If you have no need to wait for the thread's completion later, then detach it:

```
std::thread thread(ClientLoop,clientSocket);
thread.detach();
// OK to destroy now
```

If you will need to join it later, then you'll have to store it somewhere that persists beyond the loop, for example

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
while (whatever){
    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
    threads.emplace_back(ClientLoop,clientSocket);
}

// later
for (std::thread & t : threads) {
    t.join();
}

// OK to destroy now
threads.clear();
```

> This way it works, but I wonder if there are no memory leaks.

Yes, that's leaky. Each `new` creates a thread object, and you discard the pointer without deleting it or assigning it to a smart pointer to take care of. As mentioned in the comments, it not only leaks memory, but also thread handles, which on some systems are a more scarce resource; so after a while you might find that you can't launch any more threads.

Detaching a thread is the way to leave it running in the background without leaking. This causes the thread to release its resources when it finishes.

Comment: It's not only a memory leak.  Threads typically use system resources up until they are are joined, or they terminate if they are detached.  In this case, there's a good chance he'll start failing due to too many threads long before he runs out of memory.

Comment: thanks, I have just used the detach(), because I do not need to synchronize any threads.

Comment: @0x499602D2: By some people, maybe. It's not an official term in C++; but it's often used in Unix to describe a detached process, which is analagous to a detached thread.

Comment: Thanks. And a daemon thread would have to be terminated by the runtime, which occurs after the program has ended? Correct?

Comment: @0x499602D2: If it doesn't end itself before the program ends, yes.

Comment: @stefan: Although it makes little difference here, I'd prefer a vector almost anywhere. Even if you can't use `reserve` to avoid moving altogether, moving a thread is cheap, and you'll have fewer memory allocations than for a list (which will allocate a separate block for each node); and iteration tends to be faster due to locality. I'd only consider other containers if I needed something specific (stable elements, or fast insertion/removal at the start or in the middle) that `vector` didn't offer. (And if your library doesn't support move semantics, it's unlikely to support threads either.)

Comment: @stefan You still have to move to insert the elements: older versions of the STL won't support `emplace_back` either.  (And where would you find a standard library that supports threads, and doesn't support move?)

Comment: @MikeSeymour If I were to complain about something in your code, it would be the use of `emplace_back`.  Creating an object of type `std::thread` has more that a few side effects, and I don't too much like the idea that it happens without the word `thread` even appearing in the line.  I'd be in favor of using two lines here: one with `std::thread t(ClientLoop, clientSocket);`, and the next with the `push_back`.  (Of course, that might mean having to do something with the thread you've just created if the `push_back` fails; the `emplace_back` avoids this problem.)

Answer (score 9):

There's no problem creating the thread in a loop, but there may
be a problem destructing it at the end of the loop if it is
a local variable.  To be legally destructed, a thread object
must be `detach`ed, `join`ed or moved.  If your threads are
simply “fire and forget”, and you never have to
synchronize with them later (even for a clean shutdown), then
just call `std::thread::detach` on the thread after creating it.
Otherwise, you can put it into an `std::vector<std::thread>`, so
that you can find it and join it sometimes later.

Comment: ...or wrap it to RAII-object with custom behavior in destructor

Comment: shouldn't a join_all suffice?

Comment: thanks, this is also a correct answer, but I had to mark the other one due it having more explanation

Comment: @deW1 What's `join_all`?

Comment: @Drop I'm not sure that's a good idea.  You don't want a destructor accidentally detaching a thread, and you certainly don't want to to block on a `join`.

Comment: @JamesKanze nvm it doesn't exist in `std::thread`s but it does in [Boost Thread Management](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup.join_all)

Answer (score 5):

it looks as if you don't want to have to manage the lifetime of the thread (this is almost always a mistake).

If you really want to do this, it's done this way:

```
while (true){
    cout << "Waiting for new connections" << endl;
    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
    cout << "Client connected" << endl;
    thread t(ClientLoop,clientSocket);
    t.detach(); // detach the actual thread from its std::thread handle
}
```

Comment: 'this is almost always a mistake' - why?  It's an accept() thread, and it probably needs to run for the lifetime of the process.  Process-lifetime threads are far from unusual.

Comment: The short answer is that the spawning of unlimited threads is not a scalable solution. Eventually you'll need to convert the logic into an async model with a thread pool, or throttle connections against some upper limit.

Comment: That would be a fine comment if I had actually suggested spawning unlimited threads.  Since I did not....

Comment: this code will indeed spawn one thread for every inbound tcp connection. Since the timing and quantity of inbound connections is an unconstrained external input, this program it at risk of exhausting system resources as it stands. If, for example, you have 20,000 simultaneous connections, your program will attempt to create 20,001 threads. I would be amazed if you got away with that... :-)